# Should we allow recommendations of hardware or software?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, shopping

[So I just got a can of polite and friendly moderation whupass handed to me](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19873/what-good-waterproof-ipad-2-cases-are-available) on this issue (not realising it was one), and think it may be something which we should change.

I *am* new, and please don't take this is me complaining about "why my question was closed" (because I hope there's a sensible explanation for this rule). It's just that, well, I don't think I'm the only one who's tried to pull this one before.

The rule to which I am referring is thus in the [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq):

> NOT: a shopping or buying recommendation

From first principles I'd argue this rule seriously hinders the ability to help others: when someone comes to ask for help, and the best solution is a third party tool, [shouldn't we recommend it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/disk-space-disappeared-what-happened/19875#19875) Any time we come with a question, aren't we indirectly asking for recommendations of other products, if they exist and can help us? By virtue of the question we do not know if they exist.

A hypothetical user asking about some unusual messages from diskutil might be pointed in the direction of [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/): is that wrong?

Consider also that in other places on meta we seem to have tacitly [accepted](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/tag-for-alternatives-to-windows-only-applications) [recommendations](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375/are-non-apple-mac-os-x-ios-software-questions-on-topic-is-the-faq-outdated). There is even a [software recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation) tag!

Now, I find it highly specious that only software may be recommended, but not hardware. There just seems to be few good reasons for doing so. Likewise if a shopping or buying recommendation is not allowed due to the transaction of money, that would be the worst kind of free software fandom.

At the very least I must be badly misunderstanding the rules, so it would be wonderful if someone could enlighten me. But if this is a genuine inconsistency, per my arguments above, I think we should change the FAQ to *remove* the quoted rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Covered here:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

> Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — **ask us what you need to *learn* to tell what you should buy.**

Comment: That seems valid, thank you! Could we put this in the FAQ to tease out the subtle difference?

Comment: @Thomas I added "for hardware" to the end of the line in the FAQs.